# Codio is not connecting to vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, codio

I am trying to connect Codio to vs code and this is what I am getting, I am not sure why or what I can do.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01XFa.png)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are a 'student' I'd suggest you raise this with your instructors who will have set this up and know how it should be working.
If you are an instructor though, contact codio support with details of the assignment and they can take a look ?